# Why can't I kill an Activity I started using killBackgroundProcesses?

Tags: android, android-intent

OK, I'm stumped :-(

As an experiment, I've been trying to start an Activity and then sometime later shut it down using killBackgroundProcesses from the ActivityManager package. I'm not getting any errors. It just doesn't seem to do anything.

The code below is narrowed down about as much as I can get it. Just as a test, I start the Activity (successfully) and then when my onPause method gets called, I try and and stop what I had just started (in my real code, this happens much later).

Typing this up, it occurred to me that perhaps using killBackgroundProcesses on an Activity that is currently on-screen may not be meaningful. If so, is there any other way to stop this Activity? I do not have source to this other app, I started it up, and now I just want it to go away. And I also realize that this is not a normal Activity lifecycle behavior, but at least for now, this is a special case for me.

I'd appreciate any insight or solutions.

Thanks!

Manifest:

```
...
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES"/>
...
```

Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    static String PACKAGE = "com.abc.def";

    ...

    Intent i = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage( PACKAGE );
    startActivity( i );
    ...

    @Override
    protected void onPause()
    {
        // just to see if we can, kill the activity we just started
        ActivityManager manager =  (ActivityManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService( Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE );

        manager.killBackgroundProcesses( PACKAGE );     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Calling **killBackgroundProcesses** is allowed for Android framework (internal system or partner rom developers like HTC, Samsung, etc) only and not the third-party applications. Instead, you should call `finish();` on your activity's **onPause** or **onStop** method to destroy it automatically when its gone from screen.

Comment: Are you thinking of forceStopPackage? e.g. http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg103590.html I'm not sure how I would call finish() on the other activity that I want to go away. :-(

Comment: you cant get control over other people's app. you can only call this on your own activity.

Comment: When you bring your app to front, then you don't actually kill the other app, in fact your app gains focus and the other one goes to **onStop** state. Its not a bad behavior of android, its perfect, but what you are trying to accomplish is bad :)  Imagine if your app is overcome by some other people's app, how would you feel then? :)

Comment: Agreed. That's the problem. I want to stop an Activity that's not mine. I started the Activity. I know what the user is doing with the Activity. I want to stop the Activity. Bad Android behavior, but that is what I'm trying to accomplish. It appears as if the foreground/background issue is what is stopping KillBackgroundProcess from working. I found that if I force my Activity back to the front, I can kill the other Activity. Ugly - hope for a better solution

Comment: What I mean, is that after I bring my Activity to the front,  killBackgroundProcesses succeeds. I can kill the other Activity that I had previously started. I agree that this is normally very bad behavior, but it's a bit of special case.

Comment: i guess you killed your own activity with **killBackgroundProcesses** right? or is it the other app?

Comment: @Waqas- No. I killed the other Activity. My activity continues to run.

Comment: hmm strange, I thought you cant affect other apps because VM creates separate sandboxes for each process. Are you sure the other app is killed with this? any logging on its onDestroy?

Comment: It's the same thing that task-killers do. The explicit permission "KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES" is designed for this if the user has allowed it upon installing the app.